# Is it possible to get all applied Styles and not just the computed

Tags: javascript, stylesheet

Lets say you have one stylesheet with the following declaration at the top:

`a {color: black; color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)}`

So if I run `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].cssText` I get back

`a{color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)}`

Is there any possibility to get all the styles and not just the computed?

Answer (score 2):

No. `cssText` is actually an accessor, like `innerHTML`. Which means, you cannot recover any rules that the browser has eliminated. Unless you manually parse the CSS file. (...which I do not recommend. Why do you wanna do that anyway?)